# Cannot run Aleph Zero's processor in Subsquid

Tags: subsquid, indexer

is there anyone experienced in configuring Subsquid indexer who can assist me with resolving Aleph Zero Processor Configuration?

I haven't been able to locate any templates related to Aleph Zero Subsquid.

I've also raised this issue on GitHub.
https://github.com/subsquid/squid-sdk/issues/204